# Could not find transporter at usual locations. Please use environment variable `FASTLANE_ITUNES_TRANSPORTER_PATH` to specify your installation path

Tags: ios, windows, itunes, fastlane, fastlane-deliver

I am running deliver on a fastfile and I am getting this error on Windows.
Currently using ruby 2.7.8

```
[11:46:43]: Making sure the latest version on App Store Connect matches '0.2.24'...
[11:46:44]: '0.2.24' is the latest version on App Store Connect
[11:46:44]: Uploading binary to App Store Connect
[11:46:44]: Going to upload updated app to App Store Connect
[11:46:44]: This might take a few minutes. Please don't interrupt the script.
+---------------+--------------------------+
|               Lane Context               |
+---------------+--------------------------+
| PLATFORM_NAME | ios                      |
| LANE_NAME     | ios release_to_app_store |
+---------------+--------------------------+
[11:46:44]: Could not find transporter at usual locations. Please use environment variable `FASTLANE_ITUNES_TRANSPORTER_PATH` to specify your installation path.

+------+---------------------------+-------------+
|                fastlane summary                |
+------+---------------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                    | Time (in s) |
+------+---------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | app_store_connect_api_key | 0           |
|    | deliver                   | 2           |
+------+---------------------------+-------------+

[11:46:44]: fastlane finished with errors

[!] Could not find transporter at usual locations. Please use environment variable `FASTLANE_ITUNES_TRANSPORTER_PATH` to specify your installation path.
```